# How do I update text of an "anonymous" label

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I want to create a Panel:

```
public Panel MyPanel()
{
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "Monday";
        l.Name = "DayOfWeek";
        p.Controls.Add(l);

        return p;
}


public void Main()
{
        Panel SomePanel = MyPanel();
        SomePanel.Controls("DayOfWeek").Text = "Tuesday");  ///THIS LINE
}
```

I want to do something like I have on "THIS LINE" - to be able to update the label text without having to declare the label somewhere else.

Comment: Without declaring how its possible?.... and why you want like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean something like this

```
yourpanel.Controls["labelName"].Text = "Text";
```